# Missing Vin number Doors replaced

Tags: buick, vin, park-avenue

I brought a 1995 Buick Park Ave into California and the DMV will not register it because it only has the VIN on the dashboard. Both doors have been replaced and the CA DMV requires two forms of vehicle identification. Suggestions? Where is another possible location of a V
IN number?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Most all GM vehicles have a sticker on the glove compartment door which has the RPO codes on it ... it also contains the VIN on it as well. I don't know if they are looking for the VIN being on metal, but it is unique to the vehicle.

Comment: Under the hood / below the windscreen / on an inner wing panel / on a chassis member : there are usually some around the front somewhere...

Comment: Also possibly on the driver's door pillar by the latch...

Comment: Sometimes, there is a sticker in the glovebox.

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a diagram for the Buick, but most vehicles I've dealt with have had a plate somewhere in the engine bay (usually either the inner wing, the rear panel or the slam panel above the grille) with all the car details on - VIN/chassis number, colour codes, weights etc.